# Using same class for 2 xml files that uses database

Tags: java, android, xml, database

I would like to implement a database which consists of 2 tables, number and receivernumber. In fact, I have 2 xml files, one using number table, another using receivernumber. However, the code below only allows the first table to be used for both of the xmls.

Previously, I have tried implementing 2 different sets of class files, as stated below. But it crashes the entire app instead. So I tried changing to using the same class file with the receivernumber table being number2 instead. Now, both of the activity/xml file uses the first database but not the second. Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Note: there are no error logs available as it is working. Just that the table used for both activities are the same, but it's supposed to be different.

Set_numbers_to_forward.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall.DBAdapter;
import com.example.awkwardpanda_redirectcall.CallAdapter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class Set_numbers_to_forward extends Activity {

Context mContext;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
List<String> adapterData;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.set_numbers_to_forward);
    mContext = this;
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.number_list);

    adapterData = new ArrayList<String>();
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    // ---get all contacts---
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            adapterData.add(c.getString(1));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();

    adapter = new CallAdapter(this,
            R.layout.set_numbers_to_forward_editable, adapterData);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);   

} // end onCreate

public void onCreate2(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.set_number_to_receive);
    mContext = this;
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.receiver_number);

    adapterData = new ArrayList<String>();
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    // ---get all contacts---
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            adapterData.add(c.getString(1));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();

    adapter = new CallAdapter(this,
            R.layout.set_number_to_receive_editable, adapterData);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


} // end onCreate

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.addbtn, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu2(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.addbtn2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("New Phone Number");
    builder.setMessage("Enter Phone Number :");
    final EditText input = new EditText(Set_numbers_to_forward.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    input.setLayoutParams(lp);
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(mContext);
            db.open();
            db.insertContact(input.getText().toString());
            db.close();
            adapterData.add(input.getText().toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected2(MenuItem item) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("New Phone Number");
    builder.setMessage("Enter Phone Number :");
    final EditText input = new EditText(Set_numbers_to_forward.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    input.setLayoutParams(lp);
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(mContext);
            db.open();
            db.insertContact2(input.getText().toString());
            db.close();
            adapterData.add(input.getText().toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
    return true;
}

}
```

DBAdapter.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DBAdapter {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "hpnumberID";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "hpNumber";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

public static final String KEY_ROWID2 = "hpnumberID";
public static final String KEY_NAME2 = "hpNumber";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HPnumberDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "number";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "receivernumber";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table number (hpnumberID integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "hpNumber text not null);";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE2 =
        "create table receivernumber (hpnumberID integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "hpNumber text not null);";

private final Context context;    

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}


private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE2);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE2);
        onCreate(db);
    }

} // end DatabaseHelper class    

  //---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---    
public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert a contact into the database---
public long insertContact(String hpNumber) 
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, hpNumber);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

}

public long insertContact2(String hpNumber) 
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME2, hpNumber);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, initialValues);

}

//---deletes a particular contact---
public boolean deleteContact(long hpnumberID) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + hpnumberID, null) > 0;
}

public boolean deleteContact2(long hpnumberID) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE2, KEY_ROWID2 + "=" + hpnumberID, null) > 0;
}

//---retrieves all the contacts---
public Cursor getAllContacts() 
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME}, null, null,         
null, null, null);
}

public Cursor getAllContacts2() 
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE2, new String[] {KEY_ROWID2, KEY_NAME2}, null, null, 
null, null, null);
}

//---retrieves a particular contact---
public Cursor getContact(long hpnumberID) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_NAME}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + hpnumberID, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

public Cursor getContact2(long hpnumberID) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE2, new String[] {KEY_ROWID2,
            KEY_NAME2}, KEY_ROWID2 + "=" + hpnumberID, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

//---updates a contact---
public boolean updateContact(long hpnumberID, String hpNumber) 
{
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_NAME, hpNumber);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + hpnumberID, null) > 0;
}

public boolean updateContact2(long hpnumberID, String hpNumber) 
{
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_NAME2, hpNumber);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE2, args, KEY_ROWID2 + "=" + hpnumberID, null) > 0;
}


} // end DBAdapter class
```

CallAdapter.java

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CallAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

Context mContext;
List<String> list;

public CallAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> list) {
    super(context, resource, list);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mContext = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.set_numbers_to_forward_editable, parent, 
false);
    TextView hpNumber = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.hp_Number);
    ImageView discardButton = (ImageView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.number_discard_button);
    ImageView editButton = (ImageView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.number_edit_button);
    hpNumber.setText(list.get(position));
    discardButton.setTag(position);
    editButton.setTag(position);
    editButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String position = v.getTag().toString();
            createDialog(position, list);
        }

    });
    discardButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createDeleteDialog(v.getTag().toString(), list);

        }

    });
    return rowView;
}

public View getView2(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.set_number_to_receive_editable, parent, 
false);
    TextView hpNumber = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.hp_Number);
    ImageView discardButton = (ImageView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.number_discard_button);
    ImageView editButton = (ImageView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.number_edit_button);
    hpNumber.setText(list.get(position));
    discardButton.setTag(position);
    editButton.setTag(position);
    editButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String position = v.getTag().toString();
            createDialog(position, list);
        }

    });
    discardButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createDeleteDialog(v.getTag().toString(), list);

        }

    });
    return rowView;
}

public void createDialog(String position, List<String> list) {

    final long hpnumberID = Long.parseLong(position) + 1;
    final int viewPosition = Integer.parseInt(position);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setTitle("Edit");
    final EditText input = new EditText(mContext);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    input.setLayoutParams(lp);
    input.setText(list.get(viewPosition));
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(mContext);
            db.open();
            db.updateContact(hpnumberID, input.getText().toString());
            db.close();
            ((Set_numbers_to_forward) 
mContext).adapterData.remove(viewPosition);
            ((Set_numbers_to_forward) 
mContext).adapterData.add(viewPosition, input
                    .getText().toString());
            ((Set_numbers_to_forward) 
mContext).adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int 
which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
}

public void createDeleteDialog(String position, List<String> list) {

    final int viewPosition = Integer.parseInt(position);
    final long hpnumberID = Long.parseLong(position) + 1;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setMessage("Deleting \"" + list.get(viewPosition) + "\"");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(mContext);
            db.open();
            db.deleteContact(hpnumberID);
            db.close();
            ((Set_numbers_to_forward) 
mContext).adapterData.remove(viewPosition);
            ((Set_numbers_to_forward) 
mContext).adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int 
which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    builder.create().show();
}
```

}

Comment: So, did you have a question?

Comment: Am I drunk? I see everything doubled!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need doubles??
You can't use ArrayAdapter and Activity like this. Also, you don't need two xml files for this. Create an xml layout that contains two views inside and set this view as content view of your activity.

In overrided getView method in your adapter, update these views.

onCreate2 and getView2 methods are not called from anywhere and shouldn't be. In an activity, there can be only one content view.

Please see ArrayAdapter and creating Android Activity and SQLite DBAdapter examples first before starting new development.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have a question in your... question. What I can tell you is that if you setup and use your own ContentProvider it takes care of a lot of what you are doing and makes it simpler. You can read the tutorial on the android documentation here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

If you start with that feel free to leave a comment on this answer if you run into any problems with the tutorial and I might be able to help. As it is you are 'reinventing the wheel' and making things difficult for yourself

**edit**

I've just realised from Tobor's comment there's a content provider buried in there as well - I still recommend following the tutorial above (or finding your own) to clear up the code